# Send button Error

Tags: javascript, button, facebook-like, send

I am having an issue with the code for the like/send button. When you go to our website the Facebook like and send don't appear in the manner that they should. The send button only shows for 45 secs. I have timed this a few times. Until the send button "turns off" I lose some functionality of other buttons on the page. When it does "turn off" the other buttons and drop downs then work. I can't find anything in the code. Here is the code..

```
<body onload="highlight();"><a name="top" id="top"></a>
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="700" height="101"><img src="http://www.retract-a-gate.com/images/retract-a-gate_01.jpg" alt="Retractable baby gate and pet gate from Retract-A-Gate safety gates." width="700" height="101" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="55" width="700" class="safety-gate">
    <p class="safety-gate-children" style="font-margin: 0px;  position:relative;top:10px">

  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="heading" -->
    Indoor/Outdoor Retractable Safety Gate For Kids &amp; Pets
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable --></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="baby_gate_safety_gate" style="font-margin: 0px">    
   <center><em><b>"Keeps Little Ones Safer"</b></em></center><br />

<!-- facebook buttons -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Retract-A-Gate/243848942319429" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="30" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div></td>

<td width="232" valign="middle">
<div style="margin-bottom:3px;"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=www.retract-a-gate.com&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.retract-a-gate.com%2Fimages%2Fchild-safety-gate%2Fchild-safety-gate-6.jpg&description=Retractable%20safety%20gate%20for%20children%2C%20dogs%20or%20cats.%20Extremely%20durable%2C%20Use%20anywhere%20including%20the%20top%20or%20bottom%20of%20stairs%2C%20indoors%2C%20or%20outdoors.%20%20Safe%20and%20easy%20one%20hand%20operation%2C%20locks%20open%20or%20closed.%20%20Reliable%20security%20for%20baby%20or%20pet." class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal" style="margin-bottom:5ps;">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script><br /></div>
<!-- Google Pluse One Button -->
<g:plusone size="medium" annotation="none"></g:plusone><b> us on Google</b></td><td width="11">&nbsp;
</td>

<td width="221" align="center">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="search" -->
 <div style="float:right">
 <!-- Site Search --> 
 <form method="get" id="search" action="search.php">
<fieldset class="search">
  <input type="text" class="box" name="query" placeholder="Enter search terms here..." />
  <button class="btn" title="Search" value="Search"><font color="#003366"><b>Search</b></font></button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- site search -->
</div>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</td>
</tr></table>
</div>

    <table  width="684" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
<td valign="top"><a href="index.html" class="retract_a_gate">Home</a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="prices-buy-retractable-safety-gate.php" class="retract_a_gate">Prices/Buy</a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="retractable-child-baby-gate.html" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, 'anylinkmenu1')" class="retract_a_gate">Gate Info</a>
       <div id="anylinkmenu1" class="anylinkcss">
<a href="prices-buy-retractable-safety-gate.php" class="retract_a_gate">Prices/Buy</a>
<a href="retractable-child-baby-gate.php" class="retract_a_gate">Baby Gate </a>
<a href="retractable-dog-pet-gate.php" class="retract_a_gate">Dog Gate</a>
<a href="retractable-cat-pet-gate.php" class="retract_a_gate">Cat Gate</a>
<a href="retractable-safety-gate-specifications.html"  class="retract_a_gate">Dimensions &amp; Specs</a></div></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="retract-a-gate-pet-child-gate-users-guide.html" class="retract_a_gate">How
    to Use</a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="retractable-child-baby-gate-faq.php" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, 'anylinkmenu2')" class="retract_a_gate">FAQ</a>
        <div id="anylinkmenu2" class="anylinkcss">
        <a href="retractable-safety-gate-shipping-returns-faq.php" class="retract_a_gate">Shipping or Returns</a>
        <a href="retractable-child-baby-gate-faq.php" class="retract_a_gate">Baby Gate</a>
        <a href="retractable-pet-dog-gate-faq.php" class="retract_a_gate">Dog Gate</a>
        <a href="retractable-pet-cat-gate-faq.php" class="retract_a_gate">Cat Gate</a>
        </div></td>

<td valign="top"><a href="retractable-baby-gate-testimonial.html" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, 'anylinkmenu3')" class="retract_a_gate">Testimonials</a>
        <div id="anylinkmenu3" class="anylinkcss">
        <a href="retractable-baby-gate-testimonial.html" class="retract_a_gate">Baby Gate</a>
        <a href="retractable-dog-gate-testimonial.html" class="retract_a_gate">Dog Gate</a>
        <a href="retractable-cat-gate-testimonial.html" class="retract_a_gate">Cat Gate</a>
        </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><a href="about-retract-a-gate-pets-baby-gates.html" class="retract_a_gate" >About Us</a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="retract-a-gate-contact.php" class="retract_a_gate">Contact Us</a></td><td></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td valign="top" class="baby_gate_safety_gate">
   <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="pet-gate">

    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="BODY" -->


        <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
     <center>
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   
         <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td width="94">
         <center>
     <img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/NAPPA-honors-award.jpg" alt="Retract-A-Gate child and pet gates have received the NAPPA Honors Award!" title="Our retractable baby gates have won the NAPPA Honors Award" width="82" height="71" class="magnify"/></center>
         </td>
         <td colspan="5"><center>
       <a href="javascript:newWindow('retractable-gate/retract-a-gate.php?http://www.Retract-A-Gate.com','email',500,300,'')"><b>Click To Email This Page To A Friend!</b></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.retract-a-gate.com/images/boomerang3.gif" alt="Retract A Gate baby safety gates for children make great pet gates!" width="15" height="21" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#top"><b>Back To Top</b></a></center></td>

<td width="95">
<center>
<img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/made-in-usaorange.gif" alt="Retract-A-Gate baby safety gate made in the USA." width="94" height="30" title="All our retractable safety gates and products are 100% made in the USA"class="magnify"/></center>
</td>
</tr>  
         <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td width="94"><center>
     <img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/iParenting2.jpg" alt="Retract-A-Gate child and pet gates are an iParenting award winner!"  title="Our retractable baby gates have won the iParenting media award" width="82" height="78" class="magnify"/></center></td>

     <td width="83"> <center><img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/JPMA-Member.jpg" alt="Our retractable baby gate is JPMA certified from the Juvenile Products Manufacturing Association!" title="All of our retractable baby gates are JPMA certified" width="55" height="79" class="magnify" /></center></td>
     <td width="100"><center> <img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/PTPA-Seal.jpg" alt="Smart Retract has been Parent Tested and Parent Approved" title="Our retractable baby gates have been Parent Tested and Parent Approved" width="79" height="79"  class="magnify"/></center></td>
        <td width="108"> <center><img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/dubuque_chamber.gif" alt="Dubuque Chamber of Commerce Member" title="Smart Retract is part of the Dubuque Chamber of Commerece" width="80" height="89" class="magnify"/></center></td>

    <td width="95"><center> <img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/satisfaction-guaranteed2.gif" alt="Retract-A-Gate retractable pet gate - 100% satisfaction guaranteed!" title="All our retractable safety gates and products are 100% satisfaction guaranteed" width="79" height="79" class="magnify"/></center></td>

<td width="95"><center><img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/no-spam.gif" alt="Retract-A-Gate has a no spam policy"  title="Smart Retract practices a no spam policy with all our retractable safety products" width="75" height="79" class="magnify" /></center></td>

    <td width="95"><center><img src="http://www.smartretract.com/images/bbbseal1US.gif" alt="Retract-A-Gate is endorsed by the Better Business Bureau." title="Smart Retract is a Better Business Bureau Accredited business" width="47" height="76" class="magnify"/></center></td>
     </tr>
   </table></center>
     </td>
      </tr>
     </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="700" align="center">
    <img src="http://www.retract-a-gate.com/images/retract-a-gate_04.jpg" alt="Retractable baby gate and pet gate from Retract-A-Gate safety gates." width="700" height="18" /></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <h3><a href="retract-a-gate-affiliate.html" title="Retract-A-Gate Affiliate Program" class="child-safety-gates">Join
          the Retract-A-Gate retractable safety gate affiliate program!</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.retract-a-gate.com/images/boomerang3.gif" alt="Retract A Gate baby safety gates for children make great pet gates!" width="15" height="21" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:popUp('http://retract-a-gate.com/PHPSurveyor/index.php?sid=3')" class="child-safety-gates">Leave
          Feedback</a></h3>
          <p class="footer">&copy; Retract-A-Gate safety gate for children and pets. All rights reserved.<br />
             Our products are continuously improved and we reserve the right to make<br /> minor design changes or enhancements without notice.</p></td>   
  </tr>
</table>
<!--Affiliate-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.retract-a-gate.com/cgi-bin/UCInvisibleLink?merchantId=TCF"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior in?  Also, could you post the entirety of your `<body>` tag? This could be an issue where a script tag above some of your other elements is running to completion and blocking what's below if from appearing until it's done.

Comment: MattDavis I edited the original message with the whole <body> I didnt write the code originally I just found the issue and am trying to get it fixed. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am seeing it in Chrome and my boss is seeing it in Firefox. I do not get the issue in my firefox browser, or IE